# React Native Run Ios leads to black screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Hi I'm trying to use the `react-native run-ios` command, this opens up the Simulator with the tab on the top reading "iphone 6 10.3 (14E8301)" but the screen is completely black.

So far the only commands that I have run are:

```
 react-native init myapp
 cd myapp
 react-native run-ios
```

Am I missing something? I'm following a udemy tutorial and this is what the instructor has done but it is working for him

Answer (score 0):

It is usually happens when the first time you run the Simulator. You need to manually click the device type.

`Hardware => Device => iOS 10.3 => iPhone 6`

You can change `iPhone 6` to the device you want.